# Unsupported gradle method: NativeArtifact.getSourceFolders()

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I'm making a login app with firebase. I have added dependencies of firebase that are required. After adding, I synced gradle, but it is showing the error

> Unsupported method: NativeArtifact.getSourceFolders().

I have updated gradle to its latest version. I synced again, but still the same error occurred.

Comment: Which version of Android Studio are you using? And can you check the version of `com.android.tools.build:gradle:x.x.x` in your root `build.gradle` file?

Comment: I'm using Android 3.2.1

Answer (score 6):

It was the upgrade of Gradle that caused this error in your Android Studio 3.2.1. I believe that Android Studio will usually be backwards compatible with (some) previous version of Gradle. Possibly in some cases it might also work with a newer version of Gradle. However it looks like Android Studio 3.2.1 is not compatible with Gradle versions higher than 4.6 and Android Plugin newer than 3.2.1 - especially if you are using a `cmake` external native build block in your Gradle file, which I am guessing you are using (based on the error in your question).

Android Studio offered me to upgrade both Gradle and Android Plugin to a newer version as well and then build failed with the same error that you quoted.

[image]

[image]

If you do not actually need to use cmake, you can comment out the path to the cmake file `path "CMakeLists.txt"` or even better the entire `externalNativeBuild` block. I haven't experimented to what degree the newer Gradle and Android plugin will function in Android Studio 3.2.1 if you are not using CMake.

It seems that the only way out of this situation is to downgrade back to the original version of Gradle and Android plugin. OK... Or to upgrade to Android Studio 3.3. Use **caution** when upgrading to Android Studio 3.3 as this **broke the JNI / C++ integration** for me. Try the standalone ZIP file version of AS 3.3 first or make sure you have backups.

To downgrade Gradle please open `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` and change the distributionUrl to this value:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip
```

And to downgrade the Android Plugin open your root `build.gradle` file and change the classpath to:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
```

Alternatively you can also press Ctrl-Alt-Shift-S (on Windows, not sure for MacOS/Linux) to access the File -> Project Structure and switch to the Project section, where you can update both Gradle and Android Plugin versions to 4.6 and 3.2.1 respectively:

[image]

This may not solve your Firebase issue... But it should answer your question and get you back on track to solving the Firebase issue.